# Different protein ratios in similar calorie diets

Tags: diet, calories, nutrition

Consider the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

- 3000 kcal daily intake
- 250g protein

**Scenario 2:**

- 3000 kcal daily intake
- 100g protein

**Question:**

Does the protein ratio affect how much fat can be gained (in case of calorie surplus)? This means that in diets with the same amount of calories the protein-carb-fat ratio affects the quantity of fat gained.
I understand different foods have different thermic effects, but is there any logic correlation in the previous statement?

Comment: Given the recommended protein intake is 50g then even 100g is too much.  That is hard on the kidneys.

Comment: @Paparazzi those were just hypothetical scenarios to better state the question

Comment: SE is for real not hypothetical questions

Comment: @Paparazzi first the question is not hypothetical, it's quite concrete. second, your comment completely addresses another thing, which is a healthy protein daily intake. I was asking about macros ratios. Make it 10g to 50g of protein if it suits you better, but the question still stands.

Comment: Stands unanswered.   Yes something out of range will typically affect digestion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic